# Next button to navigate Access database rows

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, data-binding

I have code for when you press next button it scrolls through the database rows but i want it to display an error once it hits the last row and when you hit next it cant go any further as its the last row but it seems to keep looping on me and never ends when i hit the next button? Any ideas?
I have a variable which is = to -1 on formload.

Code:

```vb
Private Sub searchclickbinds()
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    'create data adapters
    sql = "Select * from tbl"
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "tbl")
    RecCnt = ds.Tables("tbl").Rows.Count   'how many records in ds

    TxtCI.Text = ds.Tables("tbl").Rows(inc).Item(0)

    Dim word
    word = ds.Tables("tbl").Rows(inc).Item(15)

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Caller:

```vb
Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNext.Click
    If inc <> RecCnt - 1 Then
        inc = inc + 1
        nclick()
    End If

End Sub
```

Formload:

```vb
Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    inc = -1
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you allow them to click the Next button and display an error when you could simply disable the button?  Prevention is almost always better than cure.  Also, you should get rid of all that code and use data-binding instead. Bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the controls. You can then navigate by simply call `MovePrevious` or `MoveNext` on the `BindingSource`.

Comment: Well no the error is only displayed at the last row of the table so lets say we got 10 rows i want it to display an error when you get to row 10 and you hit next again it till display that error saying no more rows.

Comment: Then you want to design bad software and I want no part of encouraging that. I will be back to help when you decide you want to write good software.

Comment: Well no it isn't bad software as it is just a college project so it wont be published, i am just instructed to make a next and previous button to scroll back and forth through data that is all and the way i was creating it was the best match. I never used this bindingsource before nor did i hear of it but i do appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Mr jmcilhinney was describing in comments (along with some other notes and observations):

```vb
' form level vars we need:
Private bsSample As BindingSource
Private dtSample As DataTable
Private ACEConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0...YOUR CONN STRING..."
```

Then loading the data:

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT Id, Name, Descr, ValueA,  Fish, Bird, Color, Active FROM Sample"

Using dbcon As New OleDbConnection(ACEConnStr)
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, dbcon)

        dbcon.Open()

        dtSample = New DataTable
        dtSample.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

    End Using
End Using
```

1. If you are just working with one table, you do not need a DataSet to store the table.
2. As shown, you dont need a DataAdapter just to fill the table, especially if you are only using them locally. You may want a form level one (like the DT or BindingSource) to make changes to the table easy: `myDa.Update(dtSample)`<sup>1</sup>
3. If you plan to add data thru the `DataTable` or display the data in a `DataGridView`, it helps specify the column order in the SQL rather than `SELECT *`
4. It is a little less true with Access, but you should open, use, then dispose of the Connection object.  One missing `con.Close` statement can result in a variety of errors.  Using blocks close and dispose of things at the end to free resources.

Note also, that if you have a `DataTable` of all Customers, you could use *that* to see if #30 exists before deleting as per a previous question.  Now the bindings:

```vb
 ' initialize BS from DT
bsSample = New BindingSource(dtSample, Nothing)

tbName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsSample, "Name")
tbDescr.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsSample, "Descr")
chkActive.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bsSample, "Active")
```

The first line initializes the `BindingSource`.  The last part sets the "mappings". For instance, the Text property of `tbName` is set to display the "Name" DB data from the `bsSample` source. The `CheckBox` will display the `Active` data (bool) as the `Checked` property.

The BindingSource has a full range of methods and properties you can use. Your Next button:

```vb
Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    bsSample.MoveNext()

    btnNext.Enabled = (bsSample.Count - 1 > bsSample.Position)
    ' To Do: add similar code for btnPrev
End Sub
```

Note that changes to the controls by the user will be applied to the `DataTable` but not the database.  If you don't want users to be able to edit this way, a simple way is to use a `DataView`:

```vb
Dim dv = New DataView(dtSample)
dv.AllowEdit = False
bsSample = New BindingSource(dv, Nothing)
```

You can also disable updates to the source on per field basis:

```vb
tbName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsSample, "Name", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never)
```

Perhaps the simplest is:

```vb
dgv.ReadOnly = True
dgv.DataSource = dtSample
```

**Do** drop a DataGridView onto the form and set the `DataSource` to your `DataTable` just to see how easy it is to use.  Too many are needlessly frightened of it.

<sup>1</sup> That is just about all there is to adding, deleting and updating any number of rows in a DataTable all at once thru a DataAdapter.  Setting them up to do this is takes a few lines of code, though surprisingly few.

Comment: I appreciate this whole thing but sadly id like to stick with my own code as the above seems way too complicated to my liking haha. I created a back to start and go to last row button which works and my previous button all works all i really need is some fix to when you go to the last row and want to press next again it will display an error saying this is the last record (row). I would use the above code but i wouldnt know how to implement this to my back to start and go to last row buttons or to do the previous as i never used binding (first to hear of it to be honest!) but thanks though!

Comment: Other than setting the bindings it is actually simpler with less code to do more compared to manually mapping it.  `MoveNext()`, `MovePrevious()`, 'MoveFirst()` and `MoveLast()`.  There is also the means to Find and Filter so you could check for #30 without firing a query.

Comment: I didnt think you could do the whole last and first part using this so that is cool i will edit my code and hopefully it will work. If i need help i will post here! Thanks again for the numerous support Plutonix!:)

Comment: If you use the Wizards they will add component versions of some of these things to the form and do all that stuff for you **but** those people never learn what's going on or how it works. Note also bullet point #2 - these things are extraordinarily powerful if you take the time to set them up and learn what they do.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty cool but for what i require is just something simple to do what i need. This is a screenshot of the section i am doing: http://imgur.com/BtwMpBm
Pretty much when you press the search button you get that above section with the first row preloaded and when you press next itl move to row number 2 and so on. With that said, i am adding the above code (I might seem like a noob here but it says ACEConnStr is not declared in which it is correct, what will i dim ACEConnStr to be?) Thanks!

Comment: Thats just your connection string.  There is no need to have it littered everywhere you open a connection, so make it a form level var.  That whole form/dialog could be driven from just 10-12 lines of code

Comment: So i do: `Dim ACEConnStr = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=.\Database.accdb")` ? I already have a `Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=.\Database.accdb")` but when i put con in there it says: value of type etc etc cannot be converted to string.

Comment: I editted the post.  One of the things wrong with what you have is DIM rather than USING.  COnnections, commands and many other DB Objects need to be disposed to prevent leaking resources.  Thats what `Using`/`End Using` does.  You apparently have a global connection when just the connection string should be global.  The code posted is working code.

Comment: So i should use "Using" rather than dim while using connections as such? Should of got you to be my tutor haha i am in college and doing VB but the tutor (teacher) didnt go through much regarding this stuff so i am learning myself as i go along! When i test the next button, row 2 loads perfectly but when i hit next again to display row 3 i get this error: This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property. Screenshot: http://imgur.com/WkB0N3X

Comment: Things like `Using` are well covered here in many many answers (including the above: see bullet #4).  The bindings only need to be added once: that `initialize BS from DT` section would be part of the previous.  Sounds like you may be adding them each time you move.  Probably best to ask a new question.  The btnNext code shown is all you need

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will ask a new question and hopefully you will be able to solve it:) I just used what you supplied on top such as the loading of data and the initialise of BS in a single sub then called it in my next button so: `nclick()
        bsSample.MovePrevious()

        btnNext.Enabled = (bsSample.Count - 1 > bsSample.Position)`